# Фигурная инициализация std::vector: множественные вложенные скобки

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Такой код компилируется:

```
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> v2 = { { {} } };
  std::vector<int> v3 { { {} } };
  std::vector<int> v4 { { { 1 } } };
  std::vector<int> v5 ({ { { 1 } } });

  return 0;
}
```

Почему? Как интерпретируются множественные фигурные скобки? Если бы была одна пара скобок, это был бы initializer_list. А во что преобразуются три пары скобок? И почему именно три, а не больше (в GCC)? (Visual Studio 2013 допускает в этой ситуации произвольное количество скобок.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Все варианты используют конструктор `std::vector<int>`, инициализирующий его из `std::intializer_list<int>`, а четвертый вариант затем еще использует конструктор копирования вектора.

В данном случае наличие или отсутствие `=` в синтаксисе лист-инициализации в первых трех вариантах роли не играет, т.е. никакой разницы в семантике первых двух вариантов нет.

1. Вариант

   ```
   std::vector<int> v2 = { { {} } };
   ```

   аналогичен

   ```
   std::intializer_list<int> temp_list = { {} };
   std::vector<int> v2 = { temp_list };
   ```

   При этом `{}` является корректным инициализатором для объекта типа `int`, т.е.

   ```
   std::intializer_list<int> temp_list = { {} };
   ```

   в свою очередь аналогично просто

   ```
   int temp_int = {}; // инициализация нулем
   std::intializer_list<int> temp_list = { temp_int };
   ```
2. Вариант

   ```
   std::vector<int> v3 { { {} } };
   ```

   это, как уже говорилось выше, то же самое, только в синтаксисе прямой лист-инициализации.
3. В варианте

   ```
   std::vector<int> v4 { { { 1 } } };
   ```

   `{ 1 }` - вполне корректный инициализатор для объекта типа `int`. Т.е. этот вариант аналогичен

   ```
   int temp_int = { 1 };
   std::intializer_list<int> temp_list = { temp_int };
   std::vector<int> v4 = { temp_list };
   ```
4. А вот вариант

   ```
   std::vector<int> v5 ({ { { 1 } } });
   ```

   использует уже конструктор копирования класса `std::vector<int>`, т.е. аналогичен

   ```
   std::vector<int> temp_vector = { { { 1 } } }; // см. вариант 3
   std::vector<int> v5(temp_vector);
   ```

   Например, если мы объявим искусственный класс

   ```
   struct S
   {
     S(std::initializer_list<int> l) {}
     S(const S&) = delete;
   };
   ```

   то первые три варианта прекрасно скомпилируются и для него, а вот четвертый - откажется компилироваться по причине удаленного конструктора копирования.

Попытки увеличивать количество скобок приводят к формированию неправильного инициализатора на самом нижнем уровне: ни `{ {} }`, ни `{ { 1 } }` уже не являются корректными инициализаторами для объекта типа `int`. Поэтому код не компилируется. Кстати, у меня и VS2015 отказывается компилировать варианты с увеличенным количеством скобок.